# VLC player build compilation failed for x86 architecture android device on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, vlc

I've been trying to use LibVLC for Android and I followed the instructions at https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile and it works perfectly for ARM. However, when trying to compile it to x86 or MIPS, I set:

export ANDROID_ABI=x86

and then compiled in the same way, but now I have a problem as it fails to compile. And show bellow error log:

```
checking if /opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r9d//toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin//i686-linux-android-gcc
--sysroot=/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r9d//platforms/android-9/arch-x86
-std=gnu99 groks SSE4.2 inline assembly... yes
    checking if /opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r9d//toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin//i686-linux-android-gcc
--sysroot=/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r9d//platforms/android-9/arch-x86
-std=gnu99 groks SSE4A inline assembly... yes
    checking if /opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r9d//toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin//i686-linux-android-gcc
--sysroot=/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r9d//platforms/android-9/arch-x86
-std=gnu99 groks 3D Now! inline assembly... yes


checking for LIVE555... no
    configure: WARNING: No package 'live555' found.
    checking for live555 version 1324598400 or later... no
    configure: WARNING: live555 is missing or its installed version is too old:
    Version 2011.12.23 or later is required to proceed.
    You can get an updated one from http://www.live555.com/liveMedia .
    configure: error: Update live555 or pass --disable-live555 to disable RTSP input support.
```

Here is one point that, I have tried it in Ubuntu 12.04 with Android 5.0.1 (API 21).
Please help what I missed?
Sorry for if any duplication question available.

Comment: android 5 <-->  ndk r9d ?? update your ndk to 10d and try again.

Comment: Yes, I have used ndk r9d. I have also tried with Android 4.4.2 and ndk r9d, but it also showed same error. Then I updated to Android 5 and got same error message again. Thank you Robert for your suggestion. I will let you know the result.

Can you say why ndk r9d works for armeabi but can't work for x86 and MIPS? What is the cause?

Thank you again.

Comment: I got "You need the NDKv8b or later" error while trying to build using "android-ndk-r10d".
Using ndk r9d it also working fine, but using ndk r10d it shows this error for armeabi, x86 and MIPS.
So what can I do now?

Comment: hmmmm. are you doing 'clean' and using 'v=1' and '-B' in your ./ndk-build

Comment: No. How can I do that? I have no idea about this. Could you please help me on that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see ndk docs.... NDK-BUILD.HTML — describes the usage of the ndk-build script

Comment: I got that problem. In compile.sh of VLC there was no case for ndk-10. So that it shows "You need the NDKv8b or later".
After updating to latest vlc source code I got new error.

********configure.in:74: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_SHARED
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.**********


[Compiled with ubuntu 14.04 and all latest version of necessary tools, NDK 9 and 10, Android Api 21]